# convert decimal to hex in table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a table similar to this one:

[image: I want something similar to this]

I uploaded the site so it can be viewed here: http://alainwebdesign.ca/CIS245/rgb.html

In the script file, I was trying to populate the "*Red Hex*" column by modifying the `generateRandomReds()` function like so:

```
function generateRandomReds(){
     for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
    var randRed = Math.random();
    randRed = randRed.toFixed(2);

      var sel = document.getElementById('genRandomReds');
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = randRed;
      opt.value = randRed;
      sel.appendChild(opt);

      //Trying to convert decimal to hex and populate the "Red Hex" 
      //column in the Generate random colors table
      //but for some reason adding this code makes it so only 1 random 
      //red decimal value is created and that's it:

      var selHex = document.getElementById('genRedHex');
      var optHex = document.createElement('option');
      optHex.innerHTML = randRed(parseInt( number , 10)).toString(16);
      optHex.value = randRed(parseInt( number , 10)).toString(16);
      selHex.appendChild(optHex);
      }
}
```

Comment: What is the question or problem ?

Comment: My question is how do I populate the "Red Hex" column in the Generate Random Colors table with values from the "Red Floats" column converted to hex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A created the following code to explain:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="generate-btn">Genarate Random Colors</button>
<br/><br/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>RGB Values</th>
     <th>RGH Hexadecimal Values</th>
     <th>Display</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener("click", generateRandom);
var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

function generateRandom() {

    tbody.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        var randR = (Math.random().toFixed(3) * 1000) % 256;
        var randG = (Math.random().toFixed(3) * 1000) % 256;
        var randB = (Math.random().toFixed(3) * 1000) % 256;       

        var rgbValue = '(' + randR + ', ' + randG + ', ' + randB + ')';
        var tdF = '<td>' + rgbValue + '</td>';

        var hexValue = '#' + randR.toString(16) + randG.toString(16) + randB.toString(16);
        var tdH = '<td>' + hexValue + '</td>';

        var display = '';
        var tdD = '<td style="background-color:' + hexValue + '"></td>';

        var tr = '<tr>' + tdF + tdH + tdD + '</tr>'        

        tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + tr;

    }
}
```

In this example I'm generating integers RBG numbers. RGB goes from 0 to 255 so a created random numbers with 3 digits with the max value of 255.
To convert to hexadecimal a simple use toString(16).

See the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alissonmbr/9nb1zq1g/